# Looking for solution to ignore animations using Kaspresso (Espresso)?

Tags: android, android-espresso, uitest

I am trying to setup Kaspresso for UI testing in my application, however I am running into a problem with animations.

1. My app uses alot of infinite animations that cause Kaspresso to hang forever.
2. Disabling animations for every component is something we don't want to go into since all our animations are custom, application is huge and each component has its own way of handling animations.
3. Apparently even blinking cursor is causing Kaspresso test to freeze waiting for animation to stop.

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to 'fake' UI thread being not busy somehow so that Kaspresso continues to run even with ongoing animations?
2. Is there any other solution that could help me with this issue?